# jQuery Ajax calls in Rails 3 getting 401 Unauthorized Request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails 3.1 application that uses devise for authentication. I am trying to make a call via ajax to a url. For some reason I keep getting 401 Unauthorized access. I have followed the tutorial here http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/05/rails-authenticity-token-with-jquery on how to authenticate jQuery requests. The code for the request is

```
        $.get('/chromosomes.json', {sequence_start: '10', sequence_end: '100'},
        function(data){
                        alert(data)
       }, 'json');
```

What is strange is that on the server I see

Started GET "/chromosomes.json?sequence_start=10&sequence_end=100&_=1320958293654" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Nov 10 15:51:33 -0500 2011
  Processing by ChromosomesController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"sequence_start"=>"10", "_"=>"1320958293654", "sequence_end"=>"100"}
Completed   in 10ms

In my controller I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index

        respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json  { render :json => @chromosomes }
    end
end
```

For some reason the authenticity session token is not being passed to Rails. If I remove the authenticate_user! before filter it works fine!? Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json  { render :json => @chromosomes }
        end

Comment: nah - you're getting an "unauthorised" response - you need to show us what before_filters are running.

Comment: The only before filter that's running in the controller is devises:   before_filter :authenticate_user!

Comment: Ok, not sure how to fix it, but that tutorial looks old (2008). This one seems more recent: http://michaelhendrickx.com/201012_jquery-ajax-with-rails-authenticity-token.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well, but I'm still getting the same authentication problem.

Comment: printf-debugging time I guess :) You need to see where in the authentication-method it's falling over. Can you tail your logs easily? If so scatter some "puts 'I'm here at point-a'" through your code and see exactly what code is getting called in what order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding :token_authenticatable to my user model. This allows users to be authenticated by session tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing using angularjs to send REST requests, so I use [ng-rails-csrf](https://github.com/xrd/ng-rails-csrf) gem to add csrf token in every ajax request sent to authenticate.