# Rails 3 devise 401 unauthorized ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I got a problem similar to this question: [jQuery Ajax calls in Rails 3 getting 401 Unauthorized Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086170/jquery-ajax-calls-in-rails-3-getting-401-unauthorized-request)

I have added token_authenticatable to my devise model.

In my action for the ajax call:

```
def rate
  params[:kon][:IP] = request.remote_ip
  params[:kon][:tag_id] = params[:id]
  @konkurrencer = Tagrating.new(params[:kon])
  @konkurrencer.save
  @konkurrencer.tag.rating_score += params[:kon][:ratings].to_i
  @konkurrencer.tag.ratings += 1
  @konkurrencer.save
  render :nothing => true
 end
```

How do I authenticate the ajax call?

How to get the token key for current user. I have tried: `<%= current_user.token_authentication_key %>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The author posted that this was a CSRF token issue. While the solution posted works, it is not secure. A better solution was proposed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175979/696610

I'm copying it here:

**You should do this:**

1. Make sure that you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your layout
2. Add `beforeSend` to all the ajax request to set the header like below:

---

```
$.ajax({ url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  data: 'someData=' + someData,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#someDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1052893/chau-hong-linh for the answer.

Comment: This is much better solution

Comment: The accepted answer for this question is dangerous from a security perspective. Please, use this answer instead!

Answer (score 1):

It was not devise giving the 401 authorized error, but CSRF token.

Just disabled it for my action:

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :rate
```

Comment: Does this mean your request action isn't secure anymore? I'm not an expert, but wouldn't this be a security issue?

Comment: That is right.. I have changed the answer to the one above for best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you only have access to the url (say you are using a plugin)

```
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var params;
  if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
    params = csrf_param + "=" + encodeURIComponent(csrf_token);
  }

  var url = "/your/path?" + params
```