# Stripe API for Ruby on Rails - Checkout button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, checkout

I'm trying to implement the Stripe payment feature on a website but the checkout button (that is supposed to redirect the visitor to the Stripe checkout page) doesn't work, since nothing happens when I click on it. Please see my code below (or [my Github repo](https://github.com/cgawlowski/BEAUTY-INC)):

/show.html.erb

```
       <div class="col-5">
        <div class="picture-details">
          <h1><%= @picture.name %></h1>
          <p><%= @picture.description %></p>
          <% if @picture.is_shopping_item == true %>
            <%= button_to "Achat", checkout_create_path, params: {id: @picture.id}, remote: true %>
          <% end %>
       </div>
```

/checkout_controller.rb

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

def create
    picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        name: picture.name,
        amount: picture.price,
        currency: 'cad',
        quantity: 1
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: root_url,
      cancel_url: root_url,
    })
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

/create.js.erb

```js
var stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:public] %>");

var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: '<%= @session.id %>'
  }).then(function (result) {
  });
});
```

And here are the credentials I get:

[credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POZjU.png)

[credentials 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M04qi.png)

I used this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEVn9sXNCAI) and I'm pretty sure I've done the credentials correctly.

Thanks for your help and let me know if you need more details :)

Comment: Are you sure that your js file is loaded? What's the console say?

Comment: Seems pretty clear the error is the call to the backend is unauthorised. Maybe look into `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` and answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861841/rails-3-devise-401-unauthorized-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are missing an `@` an `@picture` in the controller ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just tried but it still doesn't work :/ Thanks though :)